# Can i animate browsers response to element being removed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Hey i was wondering if i can animate the browsers natural response to a removal of an element?

For example, if i have a table of 4 cells in a row and i remove one of them, the browser will naturally act as he has 3 cells, so the row becomes slower ( all the cells move to the left/right).

Can i animate this browser response? can't seem to find any info on the subject,
The closest i found was :

```
target.fadeOut(300).remove();
```

Which only removes after animation so that dosen't help much.

Any enlightments on the subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this plugin, I think it has what you are after.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

More specifically, this demo: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/removing.html

Comment: It is what i'm looking for, but i can't use it because of license. Any idea how that can be achived without plugins?

Comment: With a lot of javascript. Pretty much you are going to have to fade the current element while animating all the other elements on the page into position, and then removing the element.

Comment: Could i somehow created a thread in which i just waste time and toggle between the main thread and the other? time in milisec i mean